# Can I access top template variables from nested template?

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's imagine I have a template with a nested subtemplate like this. [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/7FztN1-b-Aq)

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName  string
    SecondName string
}

type Document struct {
    DocName string
    People  []Person
}

const document = `
Document name: {{.DocName}}

{{range $person:=.People}}
{{template "person" $person}}
{{end}}

{{- define "person"}}
Person name is: {{.FirstName}} {{.SecondName}}
{{end}}
`

func main() {

    d := Document{
        DocName: "first try",
        People: []Person{
            {"Brian", "Kernighan"},
            {"Dennis", "Ritchie"},
        },
    }

    t := template.Must(template.New("document").Parse(document))

    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

All works OK, but now I want to set some document-wide variable that changes behavior in all the template and its subtemplates. Like this (not working, panics). [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/-0dhJkxM1mI)

```golang
type Person struct {
    FirstName  string
    SecondName string
}

type Document struct {
    DocName string
    People  []Person

    SwitchNameOrder bool
}

const document = `
Document name: {{.DocName}}

{{range $person:=.People}}
{{template "person" $person}}
{{end}}

{{- define "person"}}
{{if $.SwitchNameOrder}} // <---- panic here
Person name is: {{.SecondName}} {{.FirstName}}
{{else}}
Person name is: {{.FirstName}} {{.SecondName}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
`
```

How to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is to use a template function to "merge" the variable passed in to the sub-template with the variable from the parent template.

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName  string
    SecondName string
}

type Document struct {
    DocName string
    People  []Person

    SwitchNameOrder bool
}

func personWithDocument(p Person, d Document) interface{} {
    return struct {
        Person
        Document Document
    }{p, d}
}

t := template.Must(template.New("document").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "personWithDocument": personWithDocument,
}).Parse(document))
```

And then in the template you would do:

```
const document = `
Document name: {{.DocName}}

{{range $person:=.People}}
{{template "person" (personWithDocument $person $) }}
{{end}}

{{- define "person"}}
{{if .Document.SwitchNameOrder}}
Person name is: {{.SecondName}} {{.FirstName}}
{{else}}
Person name is: {{.FirstName}} {{.SecondName}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
`
```

https://play.golang.org/p/YorPsMdr9g_H

Comment: I found out how to do all of this more effectively through a template function that doesn't look - see below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635168/101152

Answer (score 2):

A better solution to the complex solutions above is to stop trying to use the top-level config option, and instead write it as a template function, with the config variable being in the function closure

```golang
{{- define "person"}}
{{if SwitchNameOrder}}
Person name is: {{.SecondName}} {{.FirstName}}
{{else}}
Person name is: {{.FirstName}} {{.SecondName}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

and

```golang
t := template.Must(template.New("document").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "SwitchNameOrder": func() bool {
        return switchNames // variable sits in closure
    },
}).Parse(document))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/O6QHtmxweOi

Other option is to write the whole switching as a string function, that is:

```
{{- define "person"}}
Person name is: {{SwitchNames .FirstName .SecondName}}
{{end}}
```

and `SwitchNames` as a string function

```
...Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "SwitchNames": func(first, second string) string {
        if switchNames {
            return second + " " + first
        }
        return first + " " + second
    },
})...
```

which can be less or more clean, depending on the actual complexity

https://play.golang.org/p/UPB3NIpzw0N

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is adding a separate struct Config and copy it everywhere. That is,

```golang
type Config struct {
    SwitchNameOrder bool
}

type Person struct {
    FirstName  string
    SecondName string

    Config Config 
    // this could also be a pointer,
    // but I don't want to deal with nils, so let's copy
}

type Document struct {
    DocName string
    People  []Person

    Config Config
}
```

and

```golang
c := Config{SwitchNameOrder: true}

d.Config = c
for _, p := range d.People {
    p.Config = c
}
```

and then just use that in the templates

```
{{- define "person"}}
{{if .Config.SwitchNameOrder}}
Person name is: {{.SecondName}} {{.FirstName}}
{{else}}
Person name is: {{.FirstName}} {{.SecondName}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

It's ugly, but what to do

https://play.golang.org/p/f95i4me8XLP