# Golang Template: Check if variable assigned within a template is set

Tags: go, go-templates

I have two templates that are combined. In the first one, a variable is set, in the second one it is used - Unfortunately, I can't change that. To test the second one, I need to check if the variable is set. But How can I do this? I tried it like that

```
{{ if not $var }}
   ...
{{ end }}
```

But that ends up with the error

`... undefined variable $var...`

I also tried it with a function in the func map, but the problem seems to be the access to $var itself. Does anyone know how to solve this?

It is NOT about checking variables that have been injected viago .Execute(...) which are accessible via `.SomeVar`, but about variables that are assigned **within** the template and are accessible via `$someVar`.

This question is NOT answered by [Can I access top template variables from nested template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629923/can-i-access-top-template-variables-from-nested-template)

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. You *CANNOT* share template variables between template scopes. Use the dot or functions to share data between templates. The [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.18.2#hdr-Variables): *"A variable's scope extends to the "end" action of the control structure ("if", "with", or "range") in which it is declared, or to the end of the template if there is no such control structure. **A template invocation does not inherit variables from the point of its invocation.**"* [proof](https://go.dev/play/p/B5wfAMgNIds).

Comment: ... or try looking for 3rd-party template lib that supports what you need.